# How to split labels of watershed segmentation in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation, watershed

I have done a watershed segmentation in OpenCV, but I want to split the segments. I thought about splitting it based on the each segment's RGB value.Since RGB value of different segments will be different. But I can't seem to find out how to do it. Anyone knows how to do this splitting based on RGB values? Or any other way of splitting the watershed segments?

What I want is to separate the two different colour zones( brown and pink in this picture) into two images or windows.

[image]

Comment: Splitting segment??? The watershed is going to give you zones/areas with different labels, not segments. Could you share an image of what your mean?

Comment: ^Hey, I have added the image and what I intend to do with it.

Comment: Can you post the original image, and the code you used to get to this result? Also, post the image in a non compressed format, such as png.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw contours of each segmented object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577297/how-to-draw-contours-of-each-segmented-object)

Comment: ^ the code is long.. I can mail it to you if you want. I could really use some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Then it is the direct result of the watershed. So let's say I is your original image, W the watershed result containing two values A and B, and Ra, Rb the two final results.

```
for all (x,y) in I
    If W(x,y) == A then Ra(x,y) = I(x,y) and Rb(x,y) = 0
    else Rb(x,y) = I(x,y) and Ra(x,y) = 0
```

Then the values of the original image are going to be in Ra and Rb according to the watershed segmentation results.

Comment: ^and that will isolate the zones?

Comment: Yes, each zone will be in a different image, surrounded by 0.

Comment: by A and B ,you mean the RGB values,ryt?

Comment: no, the result of your watershed, because you wrote in your post that it was already computed. The watershed has already separated the zones use its result.